# show text of voice and record voice Simultaneous

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problem , in my app I need to record voice and show text of it in screen simultaneous
I show the text with speech to text package and record voice with record package but the show text of voice is not true. where is problem , record package and startRecording method is true but speech to text and listen method is not true work. How to handle it ?

I try to use speech to text and record package

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!